# Who do I call for mold and rotting wood floor problem from a bad sealing at the balcony?

Tags: floor, mold, sealing

We have been moved into this house for three years (2017 build) and we slowly had some blackish bownish mold grow on side of the carpet and wall where the juliet balcony is. Because the issue didn’t look bad and it was on and off, we didn’t think to fix the problem right away. (Very dumb, we know) Since we are expecting a baby, we were trying to see if we can remove the mold and call a handyman to fix the sealing. It looks like the problem is worse than we thought with some rotting wood on the floor, and we can push with our hands and feel that it’s wet and soft.

We are wondering what company we should call to fix the problem. Should we call drywall company or flooring company?
Do we need to call mold remedition people?
Do we need to call professional handyman on top of this to fix the root cause?

Please help.. any advice would be beneficial.

Thank you.

** Adding exterior picture as well… doesn’t look like there is a problem?**
[image: Exterior]
[image: Wood pieces from rotting floor]
[image: Wet wood floor]

Comment: Great pics.  They show of the result of water infiltration.  Now get us pics of the area outside.  That is where any work will need to be done to prevent future water infiltration.

Comment: The scope of the problem isn't clear from your pictures. The repairs for such a problem are pretty intuitive except for the concept of floor and wall diaphragms. For fighting wind and earthquake, your floor is basically a giant beam tipped on its side. The rotted floor sheathing spoils the load transfer from this beam into your walls. Rotted wall sheathing spoils the transfer of the resulting wall loads down to the foundation. Hopefully the damage is a small percentage of the wall width and floor width to avoid a costly problem.

Comment: A picture of the exterior wall with the damage edges marked would be helpful for evaluating the problem's severity. A locality would be nice, too, for getting a feel for the intensity of the design loads. And do you know if your floor joists are engineered or ordinary lumber?

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I work for a general contractor, so have a bias.

With that out of the way, you need a general contractor. What I can envision is pretty substantial structural repairs, which will involve interior and exterior finishes (flooring, drywall, trim, paint, plus whatever you have on the outside) and possibly engineering. You need someone with a decent sized team to minimize the time doing the work. You need someone with relationships among the subtrades (as above) to get them in on a timely basis.

A handyman would be way out of their league. A drywaller would be inclined to just patch the wall and run. Same for a flooring specialist.

Big additional note: a 7 year old structure shouldn’t do this. You might have legal recourse with the builder.